# Is there a way of making a javascript loop to repeatedly press a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops

I am very new to javascript so bear with me if I make mistakes, I am designing a website that allows the user to change the background with a button press, this all works very well and it's great but I want the images to be able to cycle with a time delay. In essence, I want the user to be able to click a button to change the background but I also want a javascript loop running in the background clicking the same button after a set period of time, is this possible?

The code to change the background is as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var i = 0;

    $("#n").click(function () {
        i++;
        if (i > 16) { i = 1; };
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(img/' + i + '.jpg)');
    });

    $("#p").click(function () {
        i--;
        if (i <= 0) { i = 16; };
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(img/' + i + '.jpg)');
    });
});
```

And the code for the buttons used is:

```html
<button id="n" class="btn">Nxt</button>
<button id="p" class="btn">Prv</button>
```

Comment: Look up setTimeout, that should do what you want

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be *not to simulate a click* but just call the same function that the click does.

So let's make a function that can be called:

```
function increment() {
  i++;
  if ( i > 16 ){ i = 1; };
  $('body').css('background-image',  'url(img/' + i + '.jpg)');  
}
```

Then we can use that for the regular click that you already have:

```
$("#n").click(increment)
```

And we can also define a repeating call to this function:

```
setInterval(increment, 1000)
```

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrworkerGlobalScope/setInterval) is pretty neat for *non time sensitive* tasks like this. Look at the link provided to see how it works, how to cancel it if you want to stop it...

@Ritesh Ganjewala wrote a nice little snippet in [her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59599275/2306481) that will show you what `setInterval` does.

@trincot also has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59599288/2306481) that, while a little more complicated to understand, allows you to have less repeating code by using the same function to *increment* and *decrement* your counter. Which is something you should strive for when programming something. This is called the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals) for looping -

```js
setInterval(() => {
  console.log('this will repeat every 500 milliseconds');
}, 500);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i adapted this a little and it worked straight away

Comment: @user112918 if you feel this was the right answer for your question, you should mark it as accepted so that Riteh Ganjewala who is also a fairly new contributor can get a bit of reputation from it.

Answer (score 0):

By design, you can't create user inputs with JavaScript. This makes sense if you think about it, certain browser features like requesting permissions can only be done if the user performs an action. You wouldn't want sites agreeing to grant permissions without your input.

So in your case, the best thing to do would be to have the event listener (for user input) and the setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame (for automatic cycling) call the same function.

```js
document.getElementById('n').addEventListener('click', nextColor);
document.getElementById('p').addEventListener('click', prevColor);

var i = 0;

function nextColor() {
  i++;
  if ( i > 16 ){ i = 1; };
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(img/${i}.jpg)`;
}

function prevColor() {
  i--;
  if ( i <= 0 ){ i = 16; };
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(img/${i}.jpg)`;    
}

setInterval(nextColor, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't attempt to send a click event to a button. Instead isolate the function that such a click executes, and then use `setTimeout` to execute that function. You may also want to reset an ongoing timeout when the user clicks again.

Here is how that could look:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;
    var delay = 1000; // number of milliseconds 
    var timer = setTimeout(next, delay); // <-- set the time out

    function next(step=1) { // optional argument that should be 1 or -1
        i = (i + 16 + step) % 16; // Use modulo arithmetic to rotate in the range [0..15]
        $('body').css('background-image',  'url(img/' + (i+1) + '.jpg)'); 
        clearTimeout(timer); // interrupt the ongoing time out ...
        timer = setTimeout(next, delay); // <-- and start it again
    }

    $("#n").click(next);

    $("#p").click(next.bind(null, -1)); // bind the argument to be -1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), this will allow you to run a function with a fixed time delay.

```
function doThis() {
    console.log('2 seconds over ...');
}

var xyz = setInterval(doThis, 2000);
```

and if you need to stop this,

```
 clearInterval(xyz);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible...

On click of the button on which you are changing the background color you can also initiate a timeout which will call a function after the specified time period (callback function) which in your case will change the image.and setinterval will do the same repeatedly after a specified interval.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var i = 0;

  function increment() {
    i++;
    if ( i > 16 ){ i = 1; };
    $('body').css('background-image',  'url(img/' + i + '.jpg)');  
  }

  function decrement() {
    i--;
    if ( i <= 0 ){ i = 16; };
    $('body').css('background-image',  'url(img/' + i + '.jpg)');  
  }

  $("#p").click(function(){
    increment();
    setInterval(increment, 1000);
  }

  $("#n").click(function(){
    decrement();
    setInterval(decrement, 1000);
  } 

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok so ive figured something out from a couple of people who answered, what ive got now is this:

```
<script>

    setInterval(() => {
      $("#n").click();
    }, 7000);

</script>
```

This has the effect of clicking the button i want every 7 seconds and its perfect, thanks for everyones help!